# Convergence on all the measurable set

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces, cauchy-sequences, pointwise-convergence

**Problem**

On Probability space ($\Omega$, $\mathscr{A}$,P), I have sequence of $L_1$ non-negative function $f_i$ s.t.$\int_A f_i dP$ converge and $\int_A f_i dP$ is bounded by $1$ for every A $\in$ $\mathscr{A}$. The problem is the only thing I know is convergence and I do not know whether or not it converge to $\int_A f dP$ for some $f$. Is there any chance I can conclude $\int_A f_i dP$ converge to $\int_A f dP$ for some $f$?

**I have tried**

1. construct such $f$ by proving some subsequence of $f_i$ is pointwise convergence to some $f$ almost everywhere.
2. prove $f_i$ is Cauchy in $L_1$, so that this also imply existence of such $f$ by completeness and convergecne in $L_1$ gives us (1).
3. construct $f$ using simple function, but this seems difficult in abstract space $\Omega$.

None of these successed. This might be a stupid question. Could anyone help me on this? Thanks！

Comment: Didn't you ask this already? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3842263/convergence-on-every-measurable-set-imply-exist-subsequence-pointwise-convergenc

Comment: Yes. That one is not clear enough. I would delete that one now.

Answer (score 2):

For each $A \in \mathscr{A}$, since $\int_A f_i dP$ converge, let $\mu(A)= \lim_{i \to \infty} \int_A f_i dP$.

We can prove that $\mu$ is a measure (and since $\int_A f_i dP$ is bounded by $1$ for every A $\in$ $\mathscr{A}$, $\mu$ is in fact a probability). One way to prove that $\mu$ is countably additive is to apply [Vitali–Hahn–Saks theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali%E2%80%93Hahn%E2%80%93Saks_theorem).

Now, it is easy to see that $ \mu \ll P$, so by [Radon–Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) there is a finite measurable function $f$, such that, for all $A \in \mathscr{A}$,

$$ \int_A f dP = \mu(A) =\lim_{i \to \infty} \int_A f_i dP$$